# Proving a subset is a submanifold

Tags: manifolds, geometric-topology

I am given the following subset $S$ of $\mathbb{R}^{10}$,

\begin{cases}
|z_1|^2+|z_2|^2+|z_3|^2+|z_4|^2+|z_5|^2=1 \\
z_1^3+z_2^5+z_3^2+z_4^2+z_5^2=0
\end{cases}

and asked to show that it is a regular smooth submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^{10}$. (This is simply some part of $\mathbb{C}^5$ identified with $\mathbb{R}$ in the natural way.)

I understand that this amounts to showing that the space is second countable, Hausdorff and exhibits a maximal atlas.

I think that it must be Hausdorff since it is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$. However, with regards to showing second countability and exhibiting a maximal atlas, I am completely lost. I think the dimension must be $\leq 9$ since the first constraint on the elements of the subspace can be identified with a surface in $\mathbb{R}^{10}$. As well, for second countability I think that the fact that the surface is compact helps?

I would prefer hints. I am new to manifolds and want to learn the intuition for approaching problems by myself. What else should I notice about this space that may help me?

Comment: I suspect you can prove this using the preimage theorem: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preimage_theorem

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos yeah, I was thinking along those lines. Here are my thoughts. Let $f:\mathbb{R}^{10}\to\mathbb{R}$ be the first constraint. That is, it maps elements $(a+bi)\in\mathbb{R}^{10}$ to the sum of the moduli squared. So, the inverse image of $0$ is precisely the surface in $\mathbb{R}^9$. It remains only to show that 1 is a regular value. In a similar vein, we can now consider the two maps generated by identifying the real and complex parts of the second constraint with $0+0i$. And then doing the same thing with the constraint map.